# RSS лента на objective c

Tags: objective-c, xmlparser, парсер, xcode, rss

Значит так, делаю читалку rss ленты для iphone, код представлю ниже, возник вопрос, ответа на который в гугле я найти не смог, как собственно подгружать rss ленту. Тоесть на данном этапе приложение загружает и парсит 20 постов с хабра, и, собственно все, как можно реализовать дальнейшую загрузку ленты с ее открытием в приложении. Заранее спасибо за помощь. Код, собственно, вот:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TabelviewViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    NSArray *tabs;
    NSArray *searchResults;
    NSDictionary *newsItem;

}
@synthesize tabelView;
@synthesize webURL;
//@synthesize rssURL;
@synthesize urlx;
@synthesize rssData;
@synthesize news;
@synthesize currentElement;
@synthesize currentTitle;
@synthesize pubDate;
@synthesize urlPage;
//@synthesize searchBar;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // создает массив в котором содержится СПИСОК
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://habrahabr.ru/rss/feed/posts/c8d94ef9646c8e98606bdb27fe465ca0/"];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (theConnection) {
        self.rssData = [NSMutableData data];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Connection failed");
    }

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [rssData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:rssData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",result);
    self.news = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSXMLParser *rssParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:rssData];
    rssParser.delegate = self;
    [rssParser parse];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict  {

    self.currentElement = elementName;
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        self.currentTitle = [NSMutableString string];
        self.pubDate = [NSMutableString string];
        self.urlPage=[NSMutableString string];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
    } else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"pubDate"]) {
        [pubDate appendString:string];}
    else if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
        [urlPage appendString:string];

    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {
        NSDictionary *newsItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  currentTitle, @"title",
                                  pubDate, @"pubDate",
                                  urlPage,@"link", nil];
        [news addObject:newsItem];
        self.currentTitle = nil;
        self.pubDate = nil;
        self.currentElement = nil;
        self.urlPage = nil;
    }
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    [self.tabelView reloadData];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSLog(@"%@", parseError);
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];

    }
    else{
        return [news count];
    }
    return [tabs count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    newsItem = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [newsItem objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [newsItem objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
    webURL= [NSURL URLWithString:[newsItem objectForKey:@"link"]];
    newsItem=nil;
    return cell;}-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPridicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",searchText];
    searchResults=[tabs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPridicate];

}
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *) controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    return YES;

}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    indexPath=[self.tabelView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    newsItem = [news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [newsItem objectForKey:@"title"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [newsItem objectForKey:@"pubDate"];
    webURL= [NSURL URLWithString:[newsItem objectForKey:@"link"]];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showTabelDetail" sender:self];

}
-(void)tapped
{
    NSLog(@"TAPPED");
}
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    NSMutableString *fURL = [newsItem objectForKey:@"link"];
    //webURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fURL];

    TabelviewViewController *dest = segue.destinationViewController;
    dest.url=fURL;
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Кстати, хорошо, то ты дал код, а то бывает не разберешь со слов, что именно не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первое: Google Reader has been discontinued еще год назад (т.е. для тренировки - да, для развития - нет).

Второе: для чего все @synthesize? Это устарешее гэ (хотя можно устроить еще большее, если использовать).

Третье: можно и так, но я бы рекомендовал через приватную проперть

```
@implementation ViewController{
    NSArray *tabs;
    NSArray *searchResults;
    NSDictionary *newsItem;    
}
```

Кстати, не уверен, что из всех пабликов вам все нужны пабликами, но вам виднее.

Четвертое: например здесь идет проверка

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if ([currentElement isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
        [currentTitle appendString:string];
}
```

При этом string = "Захабренные / Посты / Хабралента"

currentTitle остается nil. И таких мест несколько(возможно оно там как-то работает, я пробовал без таблицы, просто дебагом).

Пятое (и самое главное): на твой запрос приходит 20 айтемов http://take.ms/PT6qc , поэтому только 20 и показывает.